# performSegue inside UIButton callback not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, segue

I have `UIButton` inside a `tableviewCell` which I'm loading from `xib`.  By clicking that button it should go to next view...  I have written call back for that..

Here's my code in xib 
   TableViewCell.h

```
typedef void(^CallBack)(UIButton *sender);

@property (copy, nonatomic) CallBack callBack;
```

TableViewCell.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (_callBack) {
    _callBack(sender);
}
```

In viewcontroller

```
cell.callBack = ^(UIButton *sender) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil];
};
```

performSegue line is hitting but its taking some time to hit... Why

Comment: probly u need to wrap that up in GCD

Comment: Do we need to use dispatch_async in view controller? @GeneCode

Comment: I think should be in your callback only. wrap the performSegue only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting UserInteractionEnabled to NO from custom UIButton and in UIView solves my issue... Thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@interface WACustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property(readwrite,copy)void (^cellCallBackMethod)(NSInteger rowIndexPath);

-(IBAction)buttonTappedFromCell:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation WACustomCell

@synthesize cellCallBackMethod;

-(IBAction)buttonTappedFromCell:(id)sender{

 self.cellCallBackMethod(0);

//any value can be given as we will retrieve this value from CellForRowAtIndex method

 }
```

In View Controller

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

cel = ....
cell.cellCallBackMethod = ^(NSInteger cellIndex)

{

    [self cellButtonTappedFromCellWithIndex:cellIndex];

};

return cell;
}

-(void)cellButtonTappedFromCellWithIndex:(NSInteger )cellIndex
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"])

    {

      ViewController1 *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

  }

}
```

Comment: like this only I did except passing index path to callback

Comment: but i tried below code. its working fine and not taking time